# Как повторять целый фрагмент в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте!
Есть следуюеще регулярное выражение:

```
^category/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+(/[\w-]+)*)_(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/(?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w-]+))/$
```

Работает оно отлично. Результат получается таким:

```
/category/categoryone/categorytwo_123/filtercode-filternameone-filternametwo/
```

И стоит задача сделать так, чтобы была возможность мультиплицировать последний ( после `/`)  участок выражения:

```
/(?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w-]+))
```

чтобы URL получился таким:

```
/category/categoryone/categorytwo_123/filtercodeone-filternameone-filternametwo/filtercodetwo-filternamethree-filternamefour/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/category/categoryone/categorytwo_123/filtercode-filternameone-filternametwo/
```

я поправил немного ваше выражение

```
^/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+(/[\w-]+)*)_(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/(?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w-]+))/$
```

Так у меня находит.

По вопросу.

```
^/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+(/[\w-]+)*)_(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/((?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w/-]+)))*/$
```

находит

```
/category/categoryone/categorytwo_123/filtercode-filternameone-filternametwo/filtercode-filternameone-filternametwo/
```

Измененная часть

```
((?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w/-]+)))*
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почти верно.
После /, вся часть воспринимается как filter_name.
Т.е. когда я на бекенде паршу эти параметры, то получается так:
'filter_code': 'filtercode', 'filter_name': 'filternameone-filternametwo/filtercode-filternamethree-filternamefour'

Я не уверен, возможно ли  вообще реализовать то, что я хочу.

Comment: Ваш ответ правильный, но так как оно дублирует именованный аргумент, результат не может быть таким, как ожидалось.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik: я так понимаю.
filtercode-filternameone-filternametwo/
filtercodetwo-filternamethree-filternamefour/ и так далее будут состоят из трех слов между которыми дефис. Неизменная основа у 1 слова - filtercode, 2 - filtername, 3 - filtername? Изменяемая часть этих слов может состоять только из латинских букв?

Comment: Состоять может из скольки угодно слов,где первое и единственное в этой части выражения - <filtercode>, остальные, и их сколько угодно - <filtername>,  и разделяются они между собой при помощи знака '-'. 
Когда эта часть выражения повторяется, она разделяется при помощи знака '/'

Но мне кажется, что тут загвоздка в том, что я пытаюсь через один именованный аргумент <filtercode>, получить несколько значений, разделённых знаком '/'